# Adding Segment Analytics to VueJS

Tags: vue.js, segment-io

I am trying to add Segment-Analytics to a VueJS app but currently, no data is being sent. I think the issue is where I am including Segment's snippet. I have so far pasted into the  tag of public.html, but I have seen other methods. I am trying to figure out the best way to do this.

here are my package.json dependencies including vue-segment-analytics:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.28",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "epic-spinners": "^1.1.0",
    "force-secure-express": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "lodash-for-vue": "^1.0.3",
    "moment-strftime": "^0.5.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-segment-analytics": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-snotify": "^3.2.1",
    "vue-sweet-calendar": "^0.3.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
```

I have added the Segment code snippet in the  tag in public/index.html.

and in my components, I have, eg:

```
mounted() {
    this.getPosts();
    window.analytics.page('Home') // from segment.io docs
  },
```

Segment is telling me that no data is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [medium post](https://luigi7up.medium.com/setup-product-analytics-in-vue-js-segment-io-amplitude-25f15f0204ea) I wrote out of frustration on how to setup **Vue 3 + Segment + Amplitude**